# I want to replace only the characters outside "" with a regular expression

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I want to get the result with regular expression

```
var text = "\"1test2test3\"test123test45test\"67test89\"";

text.replaceAll(/\"(.*)\"/g, "boom");

boom
```

but I want

```
var text = "\"1test2test3\"test123test45test\"67test89\"";

text.replaceAll(????, "boom");

"\"1test2test3\"boom123boom45boom\"67test89\"";
```

Comment: Probably the easiest and most readable way is to first split the string and only work on the substring part where you actually wan to replace something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
.replace(/("[^"]*")|test/g, (x,y) => y ? y : "boom")
```

**Details**:

- `("[^"]*")` - Capturing group 1: a `"`, then any zero or more chars other than a `"` and then a `"`
- `|` - or
- `test` - a `test` string.

The `(x,y) => y ? y : "boom"` replacement means that whenever Group 1 (`y`) matches, this group value is returned, else (if `test` is found in all other contexts), `boom` is returned.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
var text = "\"1test2test3\"test123test45test\"67test89\"";
console.log(text.replace(/("[^"]*")|test/g, (x,y) => y ? y : "boom"));
```